# Tratando de programar una acción para actualizar un registro en una BD de SQL desde ASP .NET C#, presento el siguiente error:

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

El mensaje de error es:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. El diccionario de parámetros
> contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'cedu' del tipo que no
> acepta valores NULL 'System.Int32' del método
> 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Editar(Int32)' en
> 'simoauF.Controllers.UsuariosController'. Un parámetro opcional debe
> ser un tipo de referencia, un tipo que acepte valores NULL o debe
> declararse como parámetro opcional. Nombre del parámetro: parameters
> Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web
> actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información
> acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.ArgumentException: El diccionario de
> parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'cedu' del tipo
> que no acepta valores NULL 'System.Int32' del método
> 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Editar(Int32)' en
> 'simoauF.Controllers.UsuariosController'. Un parámetro opcional debe
> ser un tipo de referencia, un tipo que acepte valores NULL o debe
> declararse como parámetro opcional. Nombre del parámetro: parameters
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la
> solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de
> la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del
> seguimiento de la pila siguiente.
>
> Seguimiento de la pila:
>
> [ArgumentException: El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada
> NULL para el parámetro 'cedu' del tipo que no acepta valores NULL
> 'System.Int32' del método 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Editar(Int32)'
> en 'simoauF.Controllers.UsuariosController'. Un parámetro opcional
> debe ser un tipo de referencia, un tipo que acepte valores NULL o debe
> declararse como parámetro opcional. Nombre del parámetro: parameters]
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo
> parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo) +527   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +91
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +29
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +10
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +35    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +10
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27    System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +29
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +22
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +29
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
> result) +9
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +9849413    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
> step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

El método que está tomando el dato cedu al que hace referencia el error es:

```
    public ActionResult Editar(int cedu)
    {
        listausuarios model = new listausuarios();
        try
        {
            using (simoauEntities db = new simoauEntities())
            {
                var ousuario = db.usuariosempre.Find(cedu);
                model.ced= ousuario.cedula;
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Y en teoría el valor está siendo enviado desde la página de la siguiente forma:

```
href="~/Usuarios/Editar/@ousuario.ced">
```

Quedando en una segunda ventana como:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(d => d.ced)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las rutas con la estructura:

```
/controlador/accion/{id}
```

Por defecto esperan que el nombre del parámetro del método se llame `id`:

```
 public ActionResult Editar(int id)
```

Por eso el error:

> El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el
> parámetro 'cedu'

En la url no hay ningún parámetro llamado `cedu`.

Para que funcione con nombre `cedu` la url debería ser así:

```
/controlador/accion?cedu=1

href="~/Usuarios/Editar/?cedu=@ousuario.ced"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estabas en lo correcto, lo cambié y funcionó perfecto